# Managing Connections in Azure Functions for Multi-Tenant Applications - preventing error: Host threshold exceeded

Tags: azure, connection, azure-functions, sandbox, multi-tenant

Azure functions run within function applications. In consumption plan, function apps run inside Azure web app sandbox, which imposes certain restrictions on what a function code is allowed to do. Most notably, there is a cap on the number of connections to external services a function app can have open at a time. The number of connections limit is currently 300. This means that a function app can have a maximum total of 300 HttpClient, CloadBlobClient, DocumentClient, and SqlClient connections. Therefore, the function code should be designed in a way to prevent opening too many connections as the requests are coming in, otherwise the function runtime will throw this error: "Host threshold exceeded". On the other hand, we don't want to re-instantiate expensive resources such as database connections, with each call to the function.

Microsoft suggests to use static variables for the connections, in order to mitigate for this limitation: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Managing-Connections  However, in a typical multi-tenant application, different tenants may be assigned different connection strings to each service. For example, we are using a catalog with entries for database and blob connection strings for each tenant. This means that using a single static variable for a CloudBlobClient, or a single SqlClient will not be an option for our case.
We have been thinking of some solutions. For example, we can create a circular list of 300 static variables to hold the connections. But then that can create additional complexities and increases the size of our runtime.

How would you tackle this problem? Do you know of any solutions for efficiently handling connections when employing Azure Functions in a typical multi-tenant application?

Comment: I'm dealing with a similar scenario but we are using DI.  I'm not sure how to implement DI in our Azure Function so that it is multi-tenant.  Have you made any progress on this issue?

Comment: We've struggled with this as well. We failed with DI on Azure Functions because there is no way to determine which tenant you're connecting to without parsing the input data which has the Tenant Id.

Addressing the static Azure Function challenge, we have static Azure Functions, but new up Services (passing in the Tenant Id) within that Static Function. This is not best practice. But it's worked for us. 

We have run into SNAT errors with port exhaustion, but only when connecting to 3rd party services within the service and failing to re-use the connection.